# Mysql: Table exists and doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, exists, not-exists

I had a table that got deleted ("filescan").  When I go to the data directory and list the files using ls, the name is not there - so it's really gone.  But in mysql, I get this:

```
mysql> select * from filescan;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db1.filescan' doesn't exist
mysql> create table filescan (id int);
ERROR 1813 (HY000): Tablespace '`db1`.`filescan`' exists.
mysql>
```

I assume that somewhere there's a table that is telling mysql that this file exists, when in fact it doesn't.  Any suggestions for dealing with this example of Schödinger's mysql table?

Comment: It looks like your database is somehow corrupted. InnoDB Or MyISAM?

Answer (score 1):

If the table that was deleted was using InnoDB storage engine (and engine isn't specified in the `CREATE TABLE` statement shown in the question, so tables are using the default ,,,  )

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'default_storage_engine'
```

and if `innodb_file_per_table` was enabled when the table was originally created, and is still enabled...

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table'
```

I'd suggest that maybe there's an orphan .ibd file in the database directory

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir'
```

From the OS command line, change directory to the database directory, and check for files that match the table name

```
 # cd /var/lib/mysql
 # cd db1
 # ls -l filescan*
```

Assuming that the table was not partitioned (again assuming InnoDB), a table should have a `filescan.frm` file and and a `filescan.ibd` file.

It sounds like the `filescan.ibd` file exists, and `filescan.frm` is missing.

If this is the case, I would consider the table to be removed.  I would relocate (move) the `filescan.ibd` file (to another directory, somewhere safe, as a backup e.g)

```
 # mv filescan.ibd /backup/
```

And then try running the `CREATE TABLE` statement again.

---

It's not at all clear how MySQL would have allowed the .frm file to be removed, and leave the .ibd file.  Most plausible explanations would be that the `.frm` file was removed from the filesystem by something other than MySQL. Or the `.frm` and `.ibd` files were removed, and the `.ibd` file was later restored.)

---

For a storage engines other than InnoDB, the problem might be something similar. (e.g. for MyISAM, the .MYD and/or .MYI files exist without a .frm file.)

Comment: You were bang on with your analysis.  Found the file and removed it, and the error message went away... and was replaced with another one,  Guess that means another question.  THANKS!  It's PROGRESS!